# How to effectively represent flags in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a function in Elixir that can end in one of states with optional flag: *ok*, *blocked*, *ok_spawned*, *blocked_spawned*. (In this case the "_spawned" is the flag.) In the future the number of states and flags can increase.

My question is - what is the best way to implement this? So I can easily check for flags / overall state?

My ideas are either Map or some tuple, where first element is base state and second is a representation of flags, but I am not sure what is better.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but the fact that your return values are so flexible might indicate a design flaw. Maybe your method just does too much? For users of the public API usually only two results are of interest: In the case of success the convention is to return `:ok` or `{:ok, return_value}`. In the case of failure you should return `{:error, reason}`. What do you expect the consumer of the method to do with all those returned flags? It seems too complex to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use atoms and a tuple:

http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/2.html#2.3-atoms

http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/2.html#2.7-tuples

Something like this maybe:

```
{:ok, nil}
{:ok, :blocked}
{:ok, :spawned}
{:blocked, :spawned}
```

But maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand how to add another state (just another atom on the first position). However, how to represent a state with two or more flags (in the future)? Let's say :ok with flags :spawned and :new_flag?

PS: I believe the second one should be {:blocked, nil}

Comment: If the number of flags is dynamic, consider using `HashSet` (http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/HashSet.html) as the second element of the tuple.

Comment: @TomášBrukner as I say, I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding your question.